# why cryptsetup cannot use /dev/fd/63 as keyfile?

Tags: sudo, gpg, luks

`# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/somedevice --key-file <(gpg2 somekeyfile.gpg)` always failed with `Failed to open key file.`
Is there any way to make this work? `--key-file -` also fails. The only thing I got to work is using named pipe. But that is annoying.

Ah, the problem is actually the sudo command cannot open the `/dev/fd/63` created by normal user. Any workaround?

## update

Since the newer cryptsetup is out for years now. The `--key-file -` bug no longer exists any more. This question now is not valid for most modern distros. following pipe will just work file:

```
gpg2 somekeyfile.gpg | sudo cryptsetup ... --key-file -
```

Comment: some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672420/using-bash-process-substitution-for-a-sudo-command

Comment: but reading key from stdin should also work.

Comment: problem is the `--key-file -` does not work. It thinks the `-` is a file name.

Comment: If sudo is involved, it'd be good if you could demonstrate the *actual command* you're running instead of the (potentially misleading) root-prompt version. Thanks!

Comment: It's reasonable in this context to answer your own question with this update and accept your own answer.

Comment: it is clarified as an useless question now rather an answer. Because we do not really solve the problem. It is now the `--key-file -` do accept stdin.

Answer (score 1):

If it's as simple as a permissions issue when using sudo you could ensure the file is opened by a subprocess of sudo rather than it's parent by passing the whole thing to bash:

```
sudo bash -c 'cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/somedevice --key-file <(gpg2 somekeyfile.gpg)'
```

Comment: I cannot accept this as an answer, because gpg command need the .gnupg or agent from the user, sudo cannot access those info.

Comment: @Wang that's more a matter for where you have your GPG keys stored and that's not really clear from your question.  But it sounds like you have a better working solution now.

Comment: in normal condition, with multi-user environments, you never had any key stored in /root

Comment: @Wang Where in your question do you describe this as a multi user environment? And I wouldn't say /root is necessarily empty just because it Is a multi user environment.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` closes all open file descriptor except 0-2 (stdin, stdout and srderr). For example:

```
$ ls -l /dev/fd/ 30</
total 0
lrwx------ 1 tim tim 64 Nov  4 20:08 0 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 tim tim 64 Nov  4 20:08 1 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 tim tim 64 Nov  4 20:08 2 -> /dev/pts/5
lr-x------ 1 tim tim 64 Nov  4 20:08 3 -> /proc/26165/fd
lr-x------ 1 tim tim 64 Nov  4 20:08 30 -> /
$ sudo ls -l /dev/fd/ 30</
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  4 20:09 0 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  4 20:09 1 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov  4 20:09 2 -> /dev/pts/5
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Nov  4 20:09 3 -> /proc/26170/fd
```

Comment: this nicely explained why it won't work. But did not provide any solution. Though this imply we may use `-C64` in sudo.